# Differences between 類似 and ような

Tags: na-adjectives

Is there any difference to how and when 類似 and ような are used? For example:

英国で同じようなことです。

英国で類似のことです。

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the meaning of the sentence? And is there any sentence to provide more context to this sentence ? Btw i think it's not ような、but 同じような. The meaning then is the same with 類似 which is look similar.

Comment: 「英国で同じようなことです。」「英国で類似のことです。」←どちらも意味がよく分かりません

Comment: My understanding of the OP's examples  is '英国で同じようなことです' means 'It's the same thing in England,' and '英国で類似のことです' means 'it's similar thing in England. Am I right jo9999?'

Comment: Yes that was my understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although "同じような" and "類似の" look like saying the same thing, there is a clear difference of the nuance.

“同じ” means “exactly same and identical.” "同じ" and　”同じような” are different. The latter means “something that looks like the same.”

“類似” means “similar to” or “resemble each other.” Thus “類似のこと” means “something similar to the other(s).” or “a thing resembling sth.”

By degree, “同じ – the same” is 100% identical, “ほぼ同じ” would mean, say 80 -90 % identical.
“類似　– similar” is, say, 70 – 90 in common, though judgemental.

In addition, "類似" sounds formal and bookish as compared with "同じような" and "似た."

Comment: It is, as you say, often a question of nuance, but good to get this clear in my head. Many thanks...

Answer (score 4):

ような is more colloquial than 類似. E.g. 類似 would be very rarely used in a conversation. Conversely, 類似 is preferred when something should sound official, e.g. `以下に類似する行為一切を禁止する`. If you say `以下のような行為一切を禁止する` it sounds slightly odd because 一切 is very formal while ような isn't.

You can also use 類似 to create nouns like 類似品、類似行為、類似物 but you can't do that with ような.

Answer (score 2):

Really hard to explain without the context of those sentences.

> 英国で同じようなことです。
>
> 英国で類似のことです。

There really is no difference between these and you would be fine to use either on them.

I will attempt to explain the differences.
Both pretty much do the same thing in a lot of circumstances.　They are both used to describe a resemblance or similarity between something eg,

> これの類似品{るいじひん}が出回{でまわ}っている
>
> これと同{おな}じような品物{しなもの}が出回{でまわ}っている

Both these are saying this:

> There are **similar** goods to this on the market

In these cases what you are doing is comparing two items with one another. Finding a common point or similarity and can be interchanged in many situations and still keep the same meaning or desired effect.

However 「ような」has another use as well which separates it from 「類似{るいじ}」.

「ような」 Can be used to describe something.

> **山{やま}のような**津波{つなみ}
>
> A **huge** tsunami wave
>
> You could also say, "A **mountain like** tsunami" using the mountain to
>   reference its size.

Or

> **化{ば}け物{もの}のような**でかい人{ひと}
>
> A **huge beast** of a person.

These examples don't show similarities so to speak as in comparing two items, more so they are describing something by using an image of another object or feature.

Answer (score 1):

I explain grammatically the difference between them.
 ような is an verbal auxiliary which indicate metaphor. 類似 is a noun which means similarity and 類似する is a verb of it.

同じような is attributive form of na-adjevtive "同じだ" + ような, it means similar. I think their meaning is same but 類似 isn't colloquial and 同じような is more common than　類似する.